# Testing My Library Against a Laravel 5.6 App

Tags: php, laravel, github, composer-php

Laravel 5.6 is coming out "soon".

I'd like to test some PHP library code against a Laravel 5.6 app prior to release.

The [laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework) repository has a 5.6 tag.  Hooray!

However, The [laravel/laravel repository](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) (where a `$ laravel new` or `$composer create-project` app comes from) doesn't have a 5.6 tag, and it's not clear if `develop`, `master`, or something else would be the right thing to grab.

My Question: How can I install a laravel app that's a good representation of what would be in Laravel 5.6 if it was released today?

Comment: According to the Lavarel homepage, "Laravel 5.6 is scheduled to be released in January 2018.", so you probably have to wait some more days for a stable version

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you for the attention.  I don't want a stable version, I want the open source thing that's currently the working version of Laravel 5.6 so I can test my code as Laravel 5.6 develops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laravel command line tool has a `--dev` flag, which will grab the latest version of Laravel in development.

```
$ laravel help new
Usage:
  new [options] [--] [<name>]

Arguments:
  name                  

Options:
      --dev             Installs the latest "development" release
```

The Laravel command

```
$ laravel new my-project --dev
```

will grab an appropriate version of `laravel/laravel` that includes the correct base composer packages (`laravel/framework`, `fideloper/proxy`, and `laravel/tinker`) for a working version of *Laravel in Development* (which at this point in time means 5.6)

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your composer.json, but you will definitely get other errors or dependency issues, I would recommend you to wait till make the release.

You also may have to upgrade your PHP version to "php": "^7.1.3", due to requirement of 5.6.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles": "dev-master",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.x-dev",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
```

Comment: + 1 for the helpful attitude, but this won't work.  While it will update the framework, it won't update the "app" that this composer.json and framework are a part of, and as noted, there are other errors that will crop up (like `"fideloper/proxy": "~3.3"` relying on constants that are no longer there)

Comment: Updates of other libraries were not part of your question, so if you don't want to perform them, don't do it. You didn't even share your composer.json to see which parts could be updated to...

Comment: @NicoHaase . I sort of did, but its easy to miss.  *However, The laravel/laravel repository* . This is the project that makes up your laravel app, and creates your default composer.json file for you.  i.e. when you say `laravel new blog`, the command creates a composer.json with `fideloper/proxy` (and others) that are part of Laravel 5.6.  So, indirecrtly, these other libraries are a part of my question.  Thank you again for time/attention!